# Creating store specific products from product->duplicate

Tags: magento-1.8, database

basically i want to create store specific versions of a product with out saving the product first and loading it back up.

I would like to do this so i can use the *core/resource_transaction* model to save all of the products at same time and rollback if something goes bad.

I have the admin store product that contains all the default values. I'm duplicating that and then setting the storeid for the product and setting store specific names, descriptions and so on...

```
$storeprod = $adminprod->duplicate();
$storeprod = $storeprod->setStoreId($germanstoreid);
$storeprod->setName($germanName);
$storeprod->setDescription($germanDesc);
```

then I'm adding all the products to transaction

```
$transactionModel = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');

foreach($products as $product){

   $transactionModel->addObject($transaction);

}

$transactionModel->save();
```

This is where i hit the rocks. The transaction save fails with a integrity constraint violation.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '246903-1' for key 'CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_PRD_ID_STOCK_ID'
```

What do i need to change in the store specific products to get the transaction to work? Is what I'm trying to do even possible, can you even create store specific products without saving the admin product first?

cheers.